# getting un expectable data in routific

Tags: java, routes, traveling-salesman, routific-api

I am using Routific for rout optimisation. but i am getting unexpected result. see below json

```
{
  "visits": {
    "order_1": {
      "location": {
        "name": "sanjay park",
        "lat": 18.56873,
        "lng": 73.90603
      },
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "12:00",
      "duration": 10,
      "priority": "high"
    },
    "order_2": {
      "location": {
        "name": "lohgon",
        "lat": 18.59113,
        "lng": 73.91882
      },
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "12:00",
      "duration": 10,
      "priority": "low"
    },
    "order_3": {
      "location": {
        "name": "kudachi",
        "lat": 16.62638,
        "lng": 74.85656
      },
      "start": "9:30",
      "end": "17:00",
      "duration": 10


    }
  },
  "fleet": {
    "vehicle_1": {
      "start_location": {
        "id": "depot",
        "name": "vidhyanager",
        "lat": 18.57997,
        "lng": 73.89432
      },
      "end_location": {
        "id": "depot",
        "name": "vidhyanager",
        "lat": 18.57997,
        "lng": 73.89432
      },
      "shift_start": "8:00",
      "shift_end": "23:00"
    }
  }
}
```

In above json i ahve assigned `"sanjay park"` as high priority and "lohgaon" as low priority but getting it is prioritizing to `"lohgaon"` location only.

see below output

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "total_travel_time": 452.23334,
  "total_idle_time": 0,
  "num_unserved": 0,
  "unserved": null,
  "solution": {
    "vehicle_1": [
      {
        "location_id": "depot",
        "location_name": "vidhyanager",
        "arrival_time": "08:54"
      },
      {
        "location_id": "order_2",
        "location_name": "lohgon",
        "arrival_time": "09:00",
        "finish_time": "09:10"
      },
      {
        "location_id": "order_1",
        "location_name": "sanjay park",
        "arrival_time": "09:15",
        "finish_time": "09:25"
      },
      {
        "location_id": "order_3",
        "location_name": "kudachi",
        "arrival_time": "13:32",
        "finish_time": "13:42"
      },
      {
        "location_id": "depot",
        "location_name": "vidhyanager",
        "arrival_time": "16:56"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

please appreciates your comments on this

Answer (score 0):

This is what the documentation states:

> `priority` allows you to make certain visits a priority over others. In some cases you have more visits than you can serve, resulting in a few unserved. But if you want to make sure your high priority visits take precedence, use this parameter and set it to "high".

So it is used to make sure that high priority orders are served. In your case, all orders are served, so this parameter doesn't do anything. If you want `sanjay park` to be served earlier in the day, you should be using the time-window constraints.